# What is DateFormat skeleton for this format?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is DateFormat skeleton for this format

`Apr-27-2020 | 12:00 PM`

I tried my best and got it halfway done.

`DateFormat("MMM-d-yyyy | h:m")`

But I don't know how to add the `AM/PM` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it now.

Answer is `DateFormat("MMM-d-yyyy | h:m a")`